# Gazetteer with shapes?

Tags: geocoding, gazetteer

I'm looking for a Gazetteer service. I only need the geocoding part and I need two entry points:

1. name look-up. Takes a query string, check for matching toponyms and
   suggest alternatives. Ideally the scope of search could be limited to
   certain items, eg only countries, regions and towns. Returns
   records with names, boundaries and an id.
2. get shape. Takes the record id and sends back the record shape coordinates as
   WKT (or other). Ideally, it can be simplified before being sent, eg
   reduce the number of points.

I have used nominatim until now but they don't allow the get by id, so if I need to download the whole polygon each time, which is less than optimal... also it can only be limited to one feature type at the time.
As an alternative, I could download and install the whole nominatim package and implement the missing features myself.

Before I go into that, I'd like to know if there is anything existing, possibly commercial product, which does what I am looking for?